# import error in Python WordCloud code.they said no module called wordcloud

Tags: python, importerror, word-cloud

I get import error in Python  WordCloud code.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package?
You can install it using pip:

```
pip install wordcloud
```

Comment: yes, I installed. But Error still appears.

Comment: Please improve your question adding the code and the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure wordcloud package is installed in the right environment. Run:

```
pip freeze
```

If you see wordcloud, then it's installed properly.

Another thing to check if your python file isn't called wordcloud too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Link;
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud

Wordcloud: a little word cloud generator.

download
wordcloud‑1.6.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl

into the folder; copy-past
C:\Python\Scripts

CMD

cd\
cd C:\Python\Scripts

install
python -m pip install wordcloud-1.6.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

pip install wordcloud

result; occurs in folder;
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages
    wordcloud
    wordcloud-1.6.0.dist-info
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive and explain the bits you kindly posted as answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using pip:

```
pip install wordcloud

python -m pip install wordcloud
```

or for specific version:

```
pip install wordcloud==1.9.2
```

For `.ipynb` file:

```
!pip install wordcloud
```